# Reference Request: Siegel Center Problem

Tags: reference-request, complex-dynamics

Does anyone have a reference to where I may find a statement of the problem and perhaps (but not required) some elementary dicussion of Siegel's Center Problem?

Comment: Siegel's own book Lectures on celestial mechanics is a good source. There is an English translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this references:
http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.525964 (A simple proof of a particular case of C. Siegel’s center theorem, by  R. de la Llave) and
http://www.math.osu.edu/~costin.10/950/tutorial_KAM.pdf (A tutorial on KAM theory, by the same author).

Also the following book "The KAM story: a friendly introduction to the content, history, and significance of classical Kolmogorov-Arnold-
Moser theory" by H.S. Dumas has a nice historical overview of the Siegel's center and related problems.